# How to get Emmtrends () to produce Bayes Factor in Rstudios

Tags: rstudio-server, emmeans, marginal-effects

I'm looking for a way to get the emtrends() function to provide a Bayes factor, as I am interested in a trend for the average effect.
More specifically a way that it would spit out the Bayes factor as well as a lower and higher density interval of the trend, so I can see the evidence strength.

*How it is being used:*

Gender effect of being one year older and wanting addition children --
effect size ( to see if there is a small gender effect compared to the average mean)

```
emtrends(NullFitH123.1,"gender", var = "age_r")
emtrends(NullFitH123.1,"gender", var = "addexp")
```

Preferably I would like to have the predictors: age, addexp, and gender all in one function, is this possible?
Happy to do it manually as well.

Your advice and expertise are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The first statement estimates, for each gender, the slopes for age_r. The second does the same with the slopes for addexp. The emtrends function does not compute bayes factors.

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by average effect. It doesn't make sense to average the age_r slopes and addexp slopes together, because those are different trends involving different predictors.

Comment: I am currently working on a Bayesian model comparison, and I'm busy with my hypothesis testing where I wanted to check the gender effects in my models.   I'm using the emtrends () as it estimates the marginal mean, which is good, I was just wondering if there is a possibility to manually change it to produce the likelihood ratio of the marginal likelihood  - which is done by base factors. Is there a function that does something similar to emtrends but that produces a bayse factor for the trends?

Comment: It's my first time using stack overflow - I heard its a good place to get advice especially when wanting to try something new. I'm not sure if its possible I'm also new to R, just thought someone would have an idea, a cool way of manipulating the function, or offering an alternative way that I haven’t thought of.

Comment: can't help much w Bayes factors. But please note that if you want marginal means, you want emmeans() not emtrends(). If you want comoarisons of narginal means, use contrast(). There are several vignettes in the emmeans package with examples of different analyses involving marginal means.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, will 100% take a look at that.